# PDF.js CORS issue for S3 file

Tags: javascript, pdf, amazon-s3, cors, pdf.js

I'm trying to view a PDF hosted on an S3 Bucket using PDF.js 1.0.571. However, I'm getting the following error:

[image: CORS error]

Working JSBin from [a similar issue](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3995):
http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-helloworld-v2/7086/edit

Not Working JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-helloworld-v2/10562/edit

My S3 CORS Setup:

[image: CORS setup]

S3 PDF for testing: http://sheethub.s3.amazonaws.com/sheets/0b26b42aa027c6b73855feb68b8c089e893f8114/original/another_guldove.pdf?1407157315

Is my CORS setup wrong? What am I missing here? Is there a difference between http://sheethub.s3.amazonaws.com and http://s3.amazonaws.com/sheethub ?

Comment: Did you find the way to do that? I'm experiencing the same problem at the moment! Also, why are you asking for the difference between the two URLs?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. It seems there's a difference in how the two URLs behave.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue as well :(

Answer (score 6):

Just like me, if someone is spending days on it.

Even after setting cors on s3

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

which is now in array format:

```
[
   {
      "AllowedHeaders":[
         "*"
      ],
      "AllowedMethods":[
         "HEAD",
         "GET"
      ],
      "AllowedOrigins":[
         "*"
      ]
   }
]
```

an doesn't works with pdf.js or any javascript code.

Just add one extra parameter with url, eg.

```
Case-1:
    var url = "https://xxxx.xxx.xxxxx?token=yyy";
    url = url + '&origin='+ window.location.host;

Case-2:
    var url = "https://xxxx.xxx.xxxxx";
    url = url + '?origin='+ window.location.host;
```

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue even after I changed my S3 like yours. I also added the '?origin=localhost'. However, nothing changes. I use CloudFront and I request it from Angular 10. Could you help me? Thx

Comment: Ok I solved my issue. I did what you wrote but had to call another PDF from my S3. The headers were not refresh by my browser. Thx

Comment: @phenric Glad to see it helpful :)

Comment: The so called "array format" here is the JSON format that is expected for S3. Works perfectly for me.

Comment: adding `origin` path parameter worked like charm.❤

Comment: @hashinclude72 I believe this answer will be life saving for many. I spent around a week to figure it out. glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 5):

For people still facing this issue and landed here :

Use this config on your S3 CORS configuration.
Follow instruction on [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html) to update your CORS config. Don't forget to save.

```
<!-- Sample policy -->
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

`<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>` makes the difference.

Answer (score -3):

You need to enable CORS on your server. Its basically done by adding the following headers to the output from your web server:

- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.yourdomain.com

You can read more about a similar case here:
http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/questions-and-answers.jsp?qa=1560/remote-hosted-pdfs-not-being-displayed-stuck-loading

Comment: the question is about S3 and a CORS config has been already done by the OP